# Block NLMS vs Affine Projection LMS

Tags: adaptive-filters, lms

I am studying Block Normalized LMS, and when I compare this with Affine Projection LMS (if updated every M samples) I think that they are the same. I would really appreciate if anyone can point out if there is a gap in my understanding. Also, I it will be really helpful if anyone can suggest some good material on Block NLMS.